# Gulp to Webpack 4 only concat and minify in an old project

Tags: webpack, webpack-4

I'm currently using **Gulp** to concatenate the `JS` and `CSS` files and then minify it, but now I want to use only **Webpack**, because I find very powerful. The problem is that I have a very old project which I have tried to use `Import` and has been an impossible task, so what I want is to pass a list `CSS` and `JS` files  and that webpack does **not** process or try to resolve the dependencies, and just **concatenate and minimize it**, in any case if I would like to process the **images** and **fonts** to pass them directly to my custom destination folder.

My question if it is possible to do this with Webpack or Webpack doesn't do just that?

Comment: Webpack is not really a total replacement for gulp, tasks like that are not very suitable for webpack. I would suggest you to keep up with gulp.

Comment: try the plugin ??  https://www.npmjs.com/package/webpack-concat-plugin

Comment: Not yet, because it doesn't support CSS, it's just JS. I think it should be possible to do only with webpack, what happens is Wepback is very complex to do it and does not understand how to get to what I'm looking for.